# Ошибка при компиляции проекта с boost?

Tags: c++, boost

Не собирается программа код ниже:

```
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/connect.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
namespace http = boost::beast::http;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    boost::asio::io_context io;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io);

    boost::asio::connect(socket, resolver.resolve("google.com", "80"));

    http::request<http::string_body> req(http::verb::get, "/", 11);

    req.set(http::field::host, "google.com");
    req.set(http::field::user_agent, BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING);

    http::write(socket, req);

    string response;
    {
        boost::beast::flat_buffer buffer;
        http::response<http::dynamic_body> res;
        http::read(socket, buffer, res);
        response = boost::beast::buffers_to_string(res.body().data());
    }

    socket.shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both);

    cout << response;

    return 0;
}
```

Компилировал при помощи g++

Версия g++

```
g++ (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Команда:

```
g++ -I Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0 -L Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0\lib64-msvc-14.1 main.cpp -o test
```

Ну и ошибка:

```
In file included from Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/beast/websocket/detail/prng.hpp:47:0,
                 from Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/beast/websocket/detail/hybi13.ipp:15,
                 from Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/beast/websocket/detail/hybi13.hpp:45,
                 from Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/beast/websocket/stream.hpp:19,
                 from Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/beast/websocket.hpp:18,
                 from Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/beast.hpp:18,
                 from main.cpp:4:
Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/beast/websocket/detail/prng.ipp: In function 'uint32_t boost::beast::websocket::detail::secure_generate()':
Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/beast/websocket/detail/prng.ipp:92:14: error: 'mutex' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
         std::mutex mtx;
              ^~~~~
Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/beast/websocket/detail/prng.ipp: In member function 'uint32_t boost::beast::websocket::detail::secure_generate()::generator::operator()()':
Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/beast/websocket/detail/prng.ipp:87:29: error: 'mutex' is not a member of 'std'
             std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard{mtx};
                             ^~~
Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/beast/websocket/detail/prng.ipp:87:29: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/asio/execution/blocking_adaptation.hpp:20:0,
                 from Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/asio/execution.hpp:22,
                 from Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/asio/system_executor.hpp:20,
                 from Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/asio/associated_executor.hpp:22,
                 from Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/beast/core/detail/bind_handler.hpp:16,
                 from Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/beast/core/bind_handler.hpp:14,
                 from Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/beast/core/async_base.hpp:14,
                 from Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/beast/core.hpp:15,
                 from Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/beast.hpp:15,
                 from main.cpp:4:
Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/asio/detail/mutex.hpp:39:19: note:   'boost::asio::detail::mutex'
 typedef win_mutex mutex;
                   ^~~~~
In file included from Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/beast/websocket/detail/prng.hpp:47:0,
                 from Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/beast/websocket/detail/hybi13.ipp:15,
                 from Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/beast/websocket/detail/hybi13.hpp:45,
                 from Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/beast/websocket/stream.hpp:19,
                 from Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/beast/websocket.hpp:18,
                 from Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/beast.hpp:18,
                 from main.cpp:4:
Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/beast/websocket/detail/prng.ipp:87:29: error: 'mutex' is not a member of 'std'
             std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard{mtx};
                             ^~~
Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/beast/websocket/detail/prng.ipp:87:29: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/asio/execution/blocking_adaptation.hpp:20:0,
                 from Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/asio/execution.hpp:22,
                 from Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/asio/system_executor.hpp:20,
                 from Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/asio/associated_executor.hpp:22,
                 from Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/beast/core/detail/bind_handler.hpp:16,
                 from Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/beast/core/bind_handler.hpp:14,
                 from Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/beast/core/async_base.hpp:14,
                 from Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/beast/core.hpp:15,
                 from Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/beast.hpp:15,
                 from main.cpp:4:
Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/asio/detail/mutex.hpp:39:19: note:   'boost::asio::detail::mutex'
 typedef win_mutex mutex;
                   ^~~~~
In file included from Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/beast/websocket/detail/prng.hpp:47:0,
                 from Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/beast/websocket/detail/hybi13.ipp:15,
                 from Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/beast/websocket/detail/hybi13.hpp:45,
                 from Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/beast/websocket/stream.hpp:19,
                 from Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/beast/websocket.hpp:18,
                 from Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/beast.hpp:18,
                 from main.cpp:4:
Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/beast/websocket/detail/prng.ipp:87:39: error: template argument 1 is invalid
             std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard{mtx};
                                       ^
Z:\boostEnd\boost_1_74_0/boost/beast/websocket/detail/prng.ipp:87:47: error: 'mtx' was not declared in this scope
             std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard{mtx};
```

Comment: Слышал, что вроде в оригинальном MinGW стандартная библиотека не умеет в многопоточность. Скачайте вместо него MinGW-w64. Лучше всего ставить его из MSYS2, там обычно самая новая версия.

Comment: Поставил и вроде стало лучше, но ошибки есть и не собирается:

`C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyRSS5q.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops16clear_last_errorEv[_ZN5boost4asio6detail10socket_ops16clear_last_errorEv]+0x10): undefined reference to `__imp_WSASetLastError'
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:`

Comment: Если бы послушали моего совета и поставили из MSYS2, у вас был бы GCC 10.2, а не древний 8.3, но тут как хотите. :) Гугл [подсказывает](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30745784/g-linker-unable-to-find-winsock-functions), что это исправляется флагом `-lwsock32`.

Comment: Видимо я что-то делаю не так, потому что даже после обновления до 10.2
`Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.`
ничего не изменилось :/

Comment: А все, при помощи флагов проблема решается :)

Comment: Угу, версия тут не важна. Это просто совет был.

Comment: 8.3 - древняя? это даже не смешно. вот 2.95 - вот это уже немножко древненькая